# Multiples Valores con Formulas

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

Tengo una formula acumulativa de valores a día actual,es de tipo condicional y bastante larga:

```
=H2+SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(H2:H185;J2:J185;"VLDO";K2:K185;"DEPOSITO";L2:L185;"MADERA"))+SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(H2:H185;J2:J185;"VLDO";K2:K185;"DEPOSITO";L2:L185;"DEPOSITO")-
SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(H2:H185;J2:J185;"VLDO";K2:K185;"MADERA";L2:L185;"DEPOSITO")+SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(H2:H185;J2:J185;"VLDO";L2:L185;"VENTA")
```

Donde va acumulando valores condicionales hasta la ultima fila ingresada (185).

Si yo por ejemplo quiero consultar el acumulativo en la fila 80 en vez de la 185, como puedo hacer para no tener que ir cambiando 185 por 80 en toda la formula?

Comment: No se entiende el texto redactado de  esa forma, usa las  funciones para mostrarlo como código.

Comment: Si copias la celda donde tienes la fórmula en la fila 185 y la pegas en la misma columna de la fila 80, Excel debería actualizar las referencias. Si la referencia a la línea 2 es constante al resto de filas, entonces la deberías fijar con el $, por ejemplo `$H$2 + SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($H$2:H185;$J$2:j185; .....`

Comment: ¿Porqué escribes todo en mayúsculas? Eso no es bien visto, y tampoco le dará más visibilidad a tu pregunta. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es la función INDIRECTO, que nos permite crear referencias a rangos mediante texto, como si lo seleccionáramos con el ratón.

[INDIRECTO (función INDIRECTO)](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/indirecto-funci%C3%B3n-indirecto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Un ejemplo sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La celda `F2` contiene el nombre del rango que quiero sumar. Con cambiarlo ahí, se cambia mi fórmula.

En las funciones de SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO, el rango a sumar y los rangos de criterios tienen que tener el mismo tamaño, así que si caambia el tamaño de 1, cambia el tamaño de todos.

Yo quiero sumar la columna A, pero solo cuando la columna B tenga una X.

Mi rango a sumar por defecto es `A2:A30` y el de criterios es `B2:B30`. Para ahorrar tiempo escribiendo, mi fórmula en F3 es:

```
=SUSTITUIR(F2;"A";"B")
```

Así mi rango de criterios se actualiza automáticamente si cambia mi rango a sumar.

La fórmula que utilizo para sumar es:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(INDIRECTO($F$2);INDIRECTO($F$3);"X")
```

Y como ves, suma perfectamente.

Ahora en F2 voy a escribir `A2:A13` y mi suma se actualiza, ignorando cualquier fila por encima de la 13:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrás que usar esta función, y tienes varios rangos de criterios, pero se puede hacer perfectamente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Elier, es perfecto

Comment: Pues si te ayudó, marca la respuesta como correcta y así se cierra la pregunta.[¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)